# John Papa's HotTowel this.handleError is undefined...Why?

Tags: knockout.js, error-handling, breeze, durandal, hottowel

I use John Papa's HotTowel template. I have a viewmodel like this:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'services/appsecurity', 'services/unitofwork', 'services/errorhandler', 'services/logger', 'services/utils'],
function (app, appsecurity, unitofwork, errorhandler, logger, utils) {

...
...

unitofwork.commit()
                .then(function () {
                    logger.logSuccess("success!", null, null, true);
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    debugger;
                    this.handleError  //UNDEFINED!!!
                });
```

If I have an error during commit process i suppose i should get a toast message or some notification about the error.
I debugged the code and realized that in the fail function "this" is the window object but it has no handleError function.

How this project template should do error handling, what i miss?

Comment: this in javascript means context, not a object. I think in your code, this = window. Is it?

Comment: I think the errorhandler service should register itself somehow to the window, and window.handleError should be defined. But how?

Comment: I would suggest read this: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/. In short, there is two ways: capture this to variable var self = this; (google for examples) or use Bind() method.

Comment: Please show us the complete file and where the `handleError` function is defined

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not displaying one. 
Try this

```
unitofwork.commit()
            .then(function () {
                logger.logSuccess("success!", null, null, true);
            })
            .fail(function () {
                var message = 'Failed Commit !!';
               logger.logError(message, error);// this will display a toast for error occured with respective moduleID name.
            });
```